# How to Clear/Delete BrowserContext folders?

Tags: jxbrowser

Using JXBrowser 6.14...

I'm using a different context for every Browser instances, that means I'm creating a temp folder for every Browser instance that I have, I've decided to remove this temp context folders when the Java application shutdown the problem is somewhere this context folders still being used for JXBrowser so I'm not able to delete them. I've also used deleteOnExit() but I'm still facing some problems with some files.

So, I'm wondering is there a way to clean up all those context files/folders? probably when the Browser disposed...?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start deleting this folder, make sure that you dispose all `Browser` instances with `BrowserContext` configured to use this folder. If you have at least one running `Browser` instance that use the folder, you won't be able to delete it.

Also, make sure that you first delete all files inside the folder, and then remove the folder (empty) itself. As far as I know Java doesn't provide API that allows deleting folder with files inside. At least 1.6. First you need to delete each file.

Comment: That's actually the approach I'm trying to implement, once the Browser is disposed delete the temp files. 
But for some reason the folder still being used. 
Any other thought?

Comment: Make sure that you don't have any running jxbrowser-chromium.exe processes when deleting the directory.

Comment: How can I kill the jxbrowser-chormium processes safe? I supposed when disposed the Browser the process kill automatically.